# How do I prove these complex problems?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I need some help on a and b

The unit circle $C$ in the complex plane consists of the complex numbers that have the distance of $1$ from origin. That will say that the complex numbers $z$ so that $|z|=1$.

a) Show that the complex number $z$ is located on $C$ if and only if $zz^\ast=1$.

What I did on a): $|z| \geq 0, zz^\ast=1 \iff |z|^2.$ So $|z|^2=1^2=1$.

b) Assume that $z$ is located in $C.$ Show that one complex number $w$ is located on the tangent to $C$ through $z$ only and only if $w=z(1+it)$ for a real number $t$. Show that this is equivalent to $w+z^2w^\ast=2z$.

b) $w-z=z(e^{\pi i/2}\cdot t) =zti$. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by part b). Is this what you'd like to show, or is this something to assume?

Comment: I edited your question so that all math expressions are typeset nicely. But please double check whether I haven't ruined any of your expressions (check if they are still how you intended them).

Comment: @chickenmancer it said, suppose/assume.

Comment: @zipirovich Yeah, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

a) $|z| = 1 \iff  z \bar{z}=1$ To proof it we will proof every side of the $\iff$

- a1) $ |z| = 1 \implies z\bar{z}=1$

  Proof: Let $z=a+ib$ and $ \bar{z}=a-ib$ then $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} =1$ so $a^2+b^2=1 $ then   $\bar{z}=a-ib$ so $z\bar{z}=(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2 = 1$
- a2) $ z\bar{z}=1 \implies |z| = 1$

  Proof: Let $z=a+ib$ then $\bar{z}=a-ib$ so
  $z\bar{z}=(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2=|z| = 1$

b) Imagine rather than working with complex numbers you were working with Euclidean 2d vectors. Same rules, same thing. Cosine product ($\cdot$) is your friend, two vectors are orthogonal if their cosine product is 0, since $cos(90)=0$. So they are on the tangent if and only if they are orthogonal. The proof then is as follows, per the definition:

Imagine $z=a+bi$ then $w= z(1+ti) = a +ati + bi  -bt =  a -bt + i(b + at)$

The vector $w-z =  a -bt - a + i(at) = -bt + ati$ then $(w-z)\cdot z= -abt +atb = 0$

This can be used in booth sense to demonstrate what you need. It is much easier than writing it here.

Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

**Part (a).** It seems to me you have the right proof, but it's not expressed well. For example, the part "$z\bar{z}=1 \Longleftrightarrow |z|^2$" doesn't make much sense, because "$|z|^2$" on the right is only an expression, not a statement. (And it's not my fault, because you confirmed that my edits didn't ruin your work.☺) Also, using the word "so" in the end makes it a sound as a one-way implication, not a two-way equivalence. It may seem like a little detail, but written like this your proof goes in one direction only.

Assuming you already know and are allowed to use the fact that $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$, a proof is pretty straightforward, and you pretty much have it:
$$z\bar{z}=1 \Longleftrightarrow |z|^2=1 \Longleftrightarrow |z|=1,$$
where the last equivalence is true precisely because $|z|\ge0$, as you said.

**Part (b).** The key is that line tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius going to the point of tangency, and I think you have that too. If $w$ lies on the tangent line to the circle $C$ at the point $z$, then $w-z$ is perpendicular to the radius from the origin to $z$. But so is $ze^{i\pi/2}$, since multiplication by $e^{i\pi/2}$ is rotation by $\pi/2$ (counterclockwise). So $w-z$ and $ze^{i\pi/2}$ have the same or opposite direction. Think of them as vectors — they are parallel. But since they don't have to have the same length, they are multiples of each other by some real coefficient $t$, so $w-z=t\cdot ze^{i\pi/2}$, or $w-z=zti$, as desired.

Now, that that's been done, we know that $w=z(1+it)$. Then $\bar{w}=\bar{z}(1-it)$, and
$$w+z^2\bar{w}=z(1+it)+z^2\bar{z}(1-it)=z(1+it)+z\cdot \underbrace{z\bar{z}}_{|z|^2=1}\cdot(1-it)=z(1+it)+z(1-it),$$
giving the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing:

Comment: Thanks. One last thing: Suppose $z_1,z_2$ is to different numbers on C so that $z_1 equals(not) -z_2.$ Show with a figure that the tangent through z_1 and z_2 intersects eachother in a point w and explain why we have to assume that z_1 equals(not) -z_2. Show that the intersection point w is given $by w=2z_1z_2 / z_1+z_2.$

Comment: we know that $|z|=1$. In addition, we know that from the center of the circle to $z$ will be a perpendicular with tangnet. We could use the formula to prove that two lines are perpendicular with $(z_3-z_1)=e^i(theta)(z_2-z_1) $For some complex numbers $z_1, z_2 and z_3$. I don't understand how this would take the form of $w+z^2w(conjugate)=2z$?

Comment: could I say that. $w+z^2w(conjugate)-2z=0$?

Comment: @zipriovich ***

Comment: Geometrically: if $z_1=-z_2$, then they are antipodal points on the circle, i.e. endpoints of the same diameter, and the tangent lines will obviously be parallel. Now assume $z_1,z_2$ lie on this circle, $z_1\neq z_1$ and $z_1\neq -z_1$, If $w$ is the point of intersection of the two tangent lines, then according to part (b) it satisfies both $w+z_1^2\bar{w}=2z_1$ and $w+z_2^2\bar{w}=2z_2$. We can view this as a system of two linear equations with two unknowns $w$ and $\bar{w}$. Solving this system for $w$ using any method, e.g Cramer's rule, will yield the desired result.

Comment: @zipriovich, Could you perhaps show how it's done with carmer's rule, since my linear algebra course starts next year and I'm curious to know how. I've done it with just standard algebra. $2((w+z^2w(conjugate)/2 * (w+z^2w(conjugate)/2))/z_1+z_2))$ and from here i solve for w and get something like this $z_1w+z_2w/z_1+z_2 =(z_1+z_2)(w)/z_1+z_2 =w$

Comment: @SamiShafi: You don't have to use Cramer's rule; you can do it by "standard algebra" too. For example, from the first equation we can find that $\bar{w}=(2z_1-w)/z_1^2=\frac{2}{z_1}-\frac{1}{z_1^2}w$ and substitute that into the second equation obtaining $w+z_2^2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{z_1}-\frac{1}{z_1^2}w\right)=2z_2$. Then we simplify this equation and solve it for $w$.

Comment: @zipriovich I understand. I'll try to solve it with Cramer's rule aswell.